# Installed g++ on top of existing XCode installation

Tags: xcode, g++

I think I've done something stupid... I use Mac OS X (10.7.5) and XCode 4.5.
Due to some programming issues I need g++ 4.4.6 but XCode only comes along with 4.2. So I've thought "Yeah, I just install the desired g++ Version". So I downloaded the corresponding gcc version from the gcc-page and performed configure - make - sudo make install.
Yeah... But with g++ --version I only get the old version 4.2...

Now I'm afraid that I "damaged" my existing Version auf g++. What steps should I perform to make everything up to normal?

I hope you could help me.

best regards
Dominik

P.s.: Yeah I still need the g++ 4.4.6 Version. Is there any possibility to get this version additionally?

Comment: Where did you install it?  By default this will be `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: I haven't altered the default settings. So it should be installed there. But if I take a look at /usr/local also other directories are changed.

Comment: I don't understand why you think you've done something stupid; if you installed into `/usr/local` then many directories will be effected, but this is normal. Have you tried `/usr/local/bin/gcc --version`?

Comment: /usr/local/bin/gcc --version
:) That gives me Version 4.4.6 :) Thank You! But is the "original" g++ Version (which comes with XCode) affected in any way? Or does XCode work as normal as usual? And last but not least: I could just assign an alias ng++=/usr/local/bin/g++ to work with the new version?

Comment: No, the old `g++` won't be affected by the new one and I wouldn't recommend using aliases; modifying the path is better.  If you want to use the old `g++` then you can `export CXX=/usr/bin/g++` or edit the `Makefile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `/usr/local/bin` to your `$PATH`.  You can make this permanent by editing `~/.profile` and adding:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export MANPATH=/usr/local/share/man:$MANPATH
```

Comment: I only have a .bash_profile in which I've already defined an alias. Should I create a .profile or just put the code you posted in the .bash_profile?

Comment: Nice :) Thank you. Now g++ --version gives me the new one. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Dominik No problem.  I think you should consider using MacPorts as that makes it trivial to install whatever piece of free software you like from source.  All the work you have performed up to this point could have been done for you by typing `sudo port install gcc44` (which would give you 4.4.7).